# Markdown file not working properly with js libraries, problem with line breaks

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am using react-markdown for rendering the markdown. I am passing the content of .md file to it, but it's not working properly, there is something wrong with the line breaks. But it works fine in the online markdown viewing tools like [this](https://dillinger.io/).

my markdown looks like this :

```
  - Type some Markdown on the left
  - See HTML in the right
  - Magic

# New Features!

  - Import a HTML file and watch it magically convert to Markdown
  - Drag and drop images (requires your Dropbox account be linked)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem with the markdown is, it should be a single line string with the line breaks represented by \n 's.

that is the above markdown should look like this.

```
  - Type some Markdown on the left\n  - See HTML in the right  \n  - Magic  \n  \n# New Features!  \n  \n  - Import a HTML file and watch it magically convert to Markdown  \n  - Drag and drop images (requires your Dropbox account be linked)
```

you can achieve this format by this code

```
mardownContent.replace(/\n/g,'  \\n')
```

or from vscode like below

[image]